# npm install does nothing - how make it work?

Tags: windows, npm, bower

I have a trouble with npm and I haven't found solution in web.

Today I wanted to start my adventure with nodejs, npm, bower etc.

I use Windows 8.1.

I installed the newest nodejs (v0.12.0). I tried these steps with both x64 and x86 builds.
I opened nodejs command line with administrative privileges.
I updated npm to 2.5.0 version.
When I run `npm install bower -g` I see a char that seems to show progress (it'is rolling) but nothing happens. Even if I leave it "working" for a 30 minutes, nothing happens. It never ends.
When I type `np ls -g` it shows only npm@2.5.0 and it's dependencies.

I don't know what other info I could provide. There are no errors nor logs.
Please, help.

**Updated**

Logs:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'node',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Lucek\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   'bower',
npm verb cli   '-g' ]
npm info using npm@2.5.0
npm info using node@v0.12.0
npm verb cache add spec bower
npm verb addNamed bower@*
npm verb addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/bower not in flight; fetching
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 08:43:01
npm verb request id 8d309c5e387572c0
npm verb etag "CQDT3LW680UJR78VNWVFLN8Q7"
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm verb get saving bower to C:\Users\Lucek\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\bower\.cache.json
npm verb addNamed bower@1.3.12
npm verb addRemoteTarball https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz not in flight; adding
npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz',
npm verb addRemoteTarball   '37de0edb3904baf90aee13384a1a379a05ee214c' ]
```

Comment: Try `npm --verbose install bower -g` and post the logs

Comment: I've attached logs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: checkout https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1198

Comment: unfortunately these solutions don't work

Comment: I've created an issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7318

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Thetoast](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7318#issuecomment-95031855) found solution that worked for me.

If you have the same problem check the value of your TEMP environment variable. To do so run nodejs' command window and type

```
echo %TEMP%
```

You should receive path to a single directory. If you receive multiple directory (as I did - I received `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp;c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\`) it means that this might by the cause of the problem. You can fix it by typing

```
SET TEMP=<correct path to temporary directory>
```

where `<correct path to temporary directory>` might by the first path (before semicolon, that means `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp` in my case).

Comment: Wow that really helped me. Shame on npm that they do not show an error message when something like this happens. Thanks a lot

Comment: you can use `setx` instead of `set` to set the environment-variable permanently

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with the `npm install bower -g` aswell but try this command:

```
npm install bower --global
```

this one worked for me

Comment: have been looking for a solution and this 1 does work for me.

Answer (score 1):

*I know this is an old question but i am adding this answer just for the record.*

I was facing a similar issue i.e. rotating character with no progress in actual installation after trying to install using the following command on linux Mint 17(from http://bower.io/#install-bower):

```
npm install -g bower
```

The command which actually worked for me is:

```
npm install --global bower
```

Note: You will need root/administrative privelage to run this command. So you might wanna use sudo.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.
But I found that this was Windows Firewall problem.

Make sure your firewall is not preventing any Incoming connections or there is no limit on TCP connections.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another solution if it helps someone - I had this issue after cloning a repo and found blowing away `node_modules` worked for me.

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was caused by Controlled Folder Access in Windows Virus and Thread Protection > Ransomware Protection > Controlled Folder Access.

[image: Windows Ransomware protection]

Turning this off fixed the problem.