# How to figure out why does the npm hang?

Tags: npm

I'm suffering from the infamous `npm install` (update) hanging problem.

So far I found following recipes:

- cleaned the cache: `npm cache clean`
- deleted npm_modules in my project
- set the registry to plain http (http://registry.npmjs.org/): `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`
- used `--loglevel=verbose` flag with `npm install`
- increased number of connections as described here:
  [Increasing the maximum number of tcp/ip connections in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux)

Yet it still hangs. The position at which it hangs seems to be random. It can be 
`npm verb get saving gulp-traceur to /home/me/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/gulp-traceur/.cache.json`; or when installing `npm verb afterAdd /home/me/.npm/q/0.9.7/package/package.json` the last package downloaded is really random.

The versions are:

> npm info using npm@2.7.5 
>   npm info using node@v0.12.0

So the question is if there is anything else I can do about it?

Comment: Might or moght not be relevant, but for the sake of people finding this question on google: try  `npm config set maxsockets 20`. Lower the actual value as needed. I had to go to as low as `5` in my case

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you have the same problem as I did but I can't make a comment to your question because I have not enough reputation.

Today somebody found solution to my similar problem. You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806771/4439713):

Comment: Thank you for the  idea! I tried it, doesn't affect the builld in any way though. I'm on ubuntu so it seems not to use the TEMP var (it wasn't set in my case at all). So far I'm getting the project built  termninating hanged build and restarting it again several times. Looks like a network or npm server problem. Maybe npm starts too may network connections which my adsl modem can't process.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to use `--force` command to make sure the cache is cleaned:
`npm cache clean --force`.
Maybe related to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627827/npm-cache-clean-not-working-angular-vs-code-as-ide).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above. I use homebrew and had to uninstall node / npm.

This worked for me:

- brew install nvm
- nvm install node

Afterwards npm started working again for me.