# 'npm cache clean' not working angular VS Code as IDE

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

> npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be
> valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\janak\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-08-11T04_38_31_995Z-debug.log

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try deleting your node_modules folder inside your project, and then run npm install again.

Comment: I was having problem with `npm cache clean` deleting `node_modules` and running with `--force` (as suggested by @A-Sharabiani) works for me.

Comment: I thinks It is not correct way for resolve this problem. I thinks correct way it is use this command "npm cache clean --force"

Comment: npm cache clean --force didn't work for me. Removing node_modules folder worked for me

Answer (score 26):

Run the command with `--force`:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Based on [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache):

> it should never be necessary to clear the cache for any reason other
>   than reclaiming disk space, thus why clean now requires --force to
>   run.

Answer (score 6):

Run the same command and just add `--force` or `-f` with it.

`npm cache clean --force`    or    `npm cache clean -f`

This error shows because you are accessing project on client terminal. please open terminal in administration mode and hit `npm cache clean` command.

Comment: will check and let you know

Comment: Have you checked. @ChanakaAmarasinghe