# Cannot install ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, npm-install

I am trying to install ioinc through nodeJS in a Windows 7 machine by typing the command

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

in cmd that I have run as administrator but the install never ends and I am stuck at this screen:

[image]

i have also tried

```
npm install i -g cordova ionic
```

or to install cordova first but the same thing happens. I also turned off windows firewall and antivirus but still nothning..

What is going on and how can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe restart of WindowS ? ;-) On try to "npm install -g ionic".

Comment: @Panta Rhei I tried that...same thing happens. it stays there for hours..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. As Lucenty described in his answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384040/npm-install-does-nothing-how-make-it-work) it was a matter of the %TEMP% variable.

Answer (score -1):

you need to install **node js** https://nodejs.org/en/download/ 
 before installing [npm install -g cordova ionic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7AcA.png)